# How to delete a user in Oracle 10 including all it's tablespace and datafiles

Tags: oracle10g

When I give the command to drop a user i.e. DROP USER 'username' cascade,

1. Does it deletes all the tablespace and datafiles used by that particular user.
2. If not, what is the command to delete all the tablespace / datafiles / disk space that   were used by that particular user.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After dropping the user, you need to, for each related tablespace, take it offline and drop it. For example if you had a user named 'SAMPLE' and two tablespaces called 'SAMPLE' and 'SAMPLE_INDEX', then you'd need to do the following:

```
DROP USER SAMPLE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLESPACE SAMPLE OFFLINE;
DROP TABLESPACE SAMPLE INCLUDING CONTENTS;
ALTER TABLESPACE SAMPLE_INDEX OFFLINE;
DROP TABLESPACE SAMPLE_INDEX INCLUDING CONTENTS;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sliff. I will try this out.
But how can I find out which all tablspaces and datafiles are associated with a given user.

Comment: Firstly I'd suggest looking through the creation scripts for your database (if existent). Otherwise use Oracle Enterprise Manager as that will tell you which tablespaces particular tables, etc. are stored in.

Comment: Thanks, I will check in Oracle Enterprise Manager.

Answer (score 7):

```
DROP USER---->
DROP USER USER_NAME CASCADE;
DROP TABLESPACE---->
DROP TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_NAME INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your help is really appreciated but explaining the code will also help. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can check which table space is used by which user with the following query.

```
SELECT USERNAME, DEFAULT_TABLESPACE FROM DBA_USERS;
```

You can also see the list of table spaces by looking at the following tables

```
DBA_TABLESPACES
USER_TABLESPACES
```