# How can I remove a user in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have 2 users in oracle database.
When I run this command, I can get 2 users have same name.

```
select * from v$pwfile_users;
```

The result as follow.
[image]

As you can see there are 2 C##user1.
2 C##user1 are different sysdba field.
I would like to remove C##user1 sysdba is true.
Thus I would like to remove the first user .
How can I remove the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a user in Oracle 10 including all it's tablespace and datafiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969245/how-to-delete-a-user-in-oracle-10-including-all-its-tablespace-and-datafiles)

Comment: hello sir.Thank you for reply.But this is different with your comment.your comment is explained tablespace. But my case is sysdba.

Comment: I think you want `REVOKE SYSDBA FROM "C##USER1"`

Comment: Hello kfinity. please write answer your comment. so I can check your answer is corrected.

Comment: And Hello kfinity . do you know how can I grant sysdba to  C##user1 ?

Comment: This is pretty interesting! How were you able to create duplicate usernames? I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: grant sysdba to c##user1 container=all;
you can create 2 users

Comment: `C##USER1` is a common user. When we create a common user in `CDB$ROOT (CON_ID=0)` the users identity is visible across all Pluggable databases (in your case CON_ID=1). To know more about common users in CDB please refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/managing-security-for-oracle-database-users.html#GUID-9F4F8738-3C10-48DB-8B59-FCBE0C9A4DF2)